# Drop rows with all zeros in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I can use `pandas` `dropna()` functionality to remove rows with some or all columns set as `NA`'s. Is there an equivalent function for dropping rows with all columns having value 0?

```
P   kt  b   tt  mky depth
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   1.1 3   4.5 2.3 9.0
```

In this example, we would like to drop the first 4 rows from the data frame.

thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, this is two questions. One, to drop columns with *all* values as 0. But also, for a function *equivalent* to dropna() which would drop columns with *any* value as 0.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It turns out this can be nicely expressed in a vectorized fashion:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,0,1]})
> df = df[(df.T != 0).any()]
> df
   a  b
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
```

Comment: Nice, but I think you can avoid negation with `df = df[(df.T != 0).any()]`

Comment: @Akavall Much better!

Comment: Just a note: OP wanted to drop `rows with all columns having value 0`, but one can infer `all` method.

Comment: @paulochf It's "some or all columns set as NA's".

Comment: @U2EF1: it's not, read again: "Is there an equivalent function for dropping rows with all columns having value 0?"

Comment: @paulochf Huh. Cool.

Comment: what is df.T? seems like an odd name

Comment: @JosephGarvin It's the transpose of `df` and is meant to match numpy's notation for the same.

Comment: All of these answers explain how can we drop rows with all zeros, However, I wanted to drop rows, with 0  in the first column. With the help of all discussion and answers in this post, I did this by doing df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0] != 0]. Just wanted to share because this problem is related to this question!!

Comment: The transpose is not necessary, any() can take an axis as a parameter. So this works: df = df[df.any(axis=1)]

Comment: Can you explain ```.any()```

Answer (score 221):

One-liner.  No transpose needed:

```
df.loc[~(df==0).all(axis=1)]
```

And for those who like symmetry, this also works...

```
df.loc[(df!=0).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: For brevity (and, in my opinion, clarity of purpose) combine this and Akavall's comment: `df.loc[(df != 0).any(1)]`. Teamwork!

Comment: +1, 30% faster that transpose -- 491 to 614 microsec, and I like the `axis=1` for being explicit; more pythonic in my opinion

Comment: Some mention should be made of difference between using .all and .any since the original question mentioned equivalence of dropna. If you want to drop all rows with any column containing a zero, you have to reverse the .all and .any in above answer. Took me awhile to realize this as I was looking for that functionality.

Comment: This does not work for me, but returns me the exact same ```df```

Comment: Is there an 'inplace' version of this? I see that to drop rows in a df as the OP requested, this would need to be `df = df.loc[(df!=0).all(axis=1)]` and `df = df.loc[(df!=0).any(axis=1)]` to drop rows with any zeros as would be the actual equivalent to dropna().

Answer (score 57):

I think this solution is  the shortest :

```
df= df[df['ColName'] != 0]
```

Comment: And its inplace too!

Comment: @MaxKleiner inplace by virtue of reassigning the variable

Comment: This solution deletes rows with AT LEAST 1 zero. The original poster asked to delete rows with ALL zeros. This is why The Unfun Cat's answer is correct.

Answer (score 34):

I look up this question about once a month and always have to dig out the best answer from the comments:

```
df.loc[(df!=0).any(1)]
```

Thanks Dan Allan!

Comment: No digging required. @8one6 has included this in his answer back in 2014 itself, the part that says: "And for those who like symmetry...".

Comment: What if you have mixed data types, some strings and a lot of number columns with zeros?

Answer (score 30):

Replace the zeros with `nan` and then drop the rows with all entries as `nan`.
After that replace `nan` with zeros.

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
```

Comment: This will fail if you have any pre-existing NaN-s in the data.

Answer (score 12):

Couple of solutions I found to be helpful while looking this up, especially for larger data sets:

```
df[(df.sum(axis=1) != 0)]       # 30% faster 
df[df.values.sum(axis=1) != 0]  # 3X faster
```

Continuing with the example from @U2EF1:

```
In [88]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,0,1]})

In [91]: %timeit df[(df.T != 0).any()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 686 µs per loop

In [92]: df[(df.sum(axis=1) != 0)]
Out[92]: 
   a  b
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1

In [95]: %timeit df[(df.sum(axis=1) != 0)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 495 µs per loop

In [96]: %timeit df[df.values.sum(axis=1) != 0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 217 µs per loop
```

On a larger dataset:

```
In [119]: bdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10000,4)))

In [120]: %timeit bdf[(bdf.T != 0).any()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

In [121]: %timeit bdf[(bdf.sum(axis=1) != 0)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop

In [122]: %timeit bdf[bdf.values.sum(axis=1) != 0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 517 µs per loop
```

Comment: Do bad things happen if your row contains a -1 and a 1?

Comment: Of course, the sum wouldn't work if you had equal rows adding up to 0. Here's a quick workaround for that which is only slightly slower:  `df[~(df.values.prod(axis=1) == 0) | ~(df.values.sum(axis=1)==0)]`

Comment: The prod() function doesn't solve anything. If you have any 0 in the row that will return 0. If you have to handle a row like this: [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1], neither of your solutions will work.

Comment: Here is a correct version that works 3x faster than the accepted answer: `bdf[np.square(bdf.values).sum(axis=1) != 0]`

Answer (score 7):

You can use a quick `lambda` function to check if all the values in a given row are `0`.  Then you can use the result of applying that `lambda` as a way to choose only the rows that match or don't match that condition:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), 
                  index=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
                  columns=list('abc'))

df.loc[['one', 'three']] = 0

print df
print df.loc[~df.apply(lambda row: (row==0).all(), axis=1)]
```

Yields:

```
              a         b         c
one    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
two    2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
three  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
four   0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
five   0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

[5 rows x 3 columns]
             a         b         c
two   2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
four  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
five  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0,0,1], 'b' : [0,0,-1]})

temp = df.abs().sum(axis=1) == 0      
df = df.drop(temp)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   a  b
2  1 -1
```

Comment: Did not work for me with a 1-column dataframe. Got `ValueError: labels [True ... ] not contained in matrix`

Comment: instead of `df = df.drop(temp)` use `df = df.drop(df[temp].index)`

Answer (score 4):

Following the example in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22650075/8443371), a more elegant solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,0,1]})
df = df[df.any(axis=1)]
print(df)

   a  b
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
# Is there anything in this row non-zero?
# df != 0 --> which entries are non-zero? T/F
# (df != 0).any(axis=1) --> are there 'any' entries non-zero row-wise? T/F of rows that return true to this statement.
# df.loc[all_zero_mask,:] --> mask your rows to only show the rows which contained a non-zero entry.
# df.shape to confirm a subset.

all_zero_mask=(df != 0).any(axis=1) # Is there anything in this row non-zero?
df.loc[all_zero_mask,:].shape
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me
`new_df = df[df.loc[:]!=0].dropna()`

Answer (score 1):

For me this code: `df.loc[(df!=0).any(axis=0)]`
did not work. It returned the exact dataset.

Instead, I used `df.loc[:, (df!=0).any(axis=0)]` and dropped all the columns with 0 values in the dataset

The function `.all()` droped all the columns in which are any zero values in my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df [~( df [ ['kt'  'b'   'tt'  'mky' 'depth', ] ] == 0).all(axis=1) ]
```

Try this command its perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing only the indices that are TRUE for the row sum > 0 should suffice:

```
ndf=df[df.sum(axis=1)>0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

s = '''
P   kt  b   tt  mky depth
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   1.1 3   4.5 2.3 9.0
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r'\s+', engine='python',index_col=0)
print(df)
print()
print(
    df.where(df != 0).dropna(how='all')
)
```

Answer (score -2):

To drop all columns with values 0 in any row:

```
new_df = df[df.loc[:]!=0].dropna()
```