# Pandas DataFrame, How do I remove all columns and rows that sum to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame with rows and columns that sum to 0.

```
    A   B   C    D
0   1   1   0    1
1   0   0   0    0 
2   1   0   0    1
3   0   1   0    0  
4   1   1   0    1
```

The end result should be

```
    A   B    D
0   1   1    1
2   1   0    1
3   0   1    0  
4   1   1    1
```

Notice the rows and columns that only had zeros have been removed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`df.loc[row_indexer, column_indexer]` allows you to select rows and columns using boolean masks:

```
In [88]: df.loc[(df.sum(axis=1) != 0), (df.sum(axis=0) != 0)]
Out[88]: 
   A  B  D
0  1  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  0
4  1  1  1

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

`df.sum(axis=1) != 0` is True if and only if the row does not sum to 0.

`df.sum(axis=0) != 0` is True if and only if the column does not sum to 0.

Comment: Of all the rare times it is appropriate to use the term "iff" and you missed it!

Comment: @Cyber: It's the Zen of Python: simple is better than complex; readability counts :)

Comment: And if you want to select all rows but only columns that don't sum to zero: `df.loc[:, (df.sum(axis=0) != 0)]`

Answer (score 7):

building on [Drop rows with all zeros in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame) to avoid using the sum()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,0,1,0,1],
                   'B': [1,0,0,1,1],
                   'C': [0,0,0,0,0],
                   'D': [1,0,1,0,1]})

df.loc[(df!=0).any(1), (df!=0).any(0)]

   A  B  D
0  1  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  0
4  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd 
hl = []
df =  pd.read_csv("my.csv")
l = list(df.columns.values)
for l in l:
    if sum(df[l]) != 0:
        hl.append(l)
df2 = df[hl]
```

to write reduced_Data:

```
df2.to_csv("my_reduced_data.csv")
```

It will  only check columns but ignore Rows