# Drop all columns where all values are zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple question which relates to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573052/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-remove-all-columns-and-rows-that-sum-to-0), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame).

I am trying to drop all columns from a pandas dataframe, which have only zeroes (vertically, `axis=1`). Let me give you an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,0], 'b':[0,-1,0,1]})

    a   b
0   0   0
1   0  -1
2   0   0
3   0   1
```

I'd like to drop column `a`since it has only zeroes.

However, I'd like to do it in a nice and vectorized fashion if possible. My data set is huge - so I don't want to loop. Hence I tried

```
df = df.loc[(df).any(1), (df!=0).any(0)]

    b
1  -1
3   1
```

Which allows me to drop both columns and rows. But if I just try to drop the columns, `loc`seems to fail. Any ideas?

Comment: Why was Max's answer downvoted? Do you want `b`?

Comment: But, you do want column b, correct?

Comment: I want to drop all columns which sum up to zero.

Comment: @ayhan, it wasn't correct becuase `sum([-1, 1, -1, 1])` gives `0`

Comment: True, but it's ment to say that. I will edit it.

Comment: @ayhan, somehow i had a feeling that it's not what OP really wants... I might be wrong of course...

Comment: @MaxU If OP asked for sum = 0 then your answer is wrong.. I think

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i've updated my post ... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a matter of 0s and not sum, use `df.any`:

```
In [291]: df.T[df.any()].T
Out[291]: 
   b
0  0
1 -1
2  0
3  1
```

Alternatively:

```
In [296]: df.T[(df != 0).any()].T # or df.loc[:, (df != 0).any()]
Out[296]: 
   b
0  0
1 -1
2  0
3  1
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for helping me setting the question right!

Comment: @Rachel Make sure you know what you want well in advance next time... cheers. :-)

Answer (score 15):

You are really close, use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) - `0` are casted to `False`s:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.any()]
print (df)

   b
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

Comment: Great answer! But @coldspeed was the first to answer it. Though I timed it, and your solution seems to be the fastest! Thank you!

Comment: You are right. This time, it is really difficult. Coldspeed helped me set the question right and aswered it. So I think Coldspeed deserves the checked answer this time. What is the policy here? Don't find anything in Beta...

Comment: @Rachel - if need faster solution, need maxu or my answer, because double transpose is slow. And who is winner - who get accepted answer - is up to you.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [73]: df.loc[:, df.ne(0).any()]
Out[73]:
   b
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

or:

```
In [71]: df.loc[:, ~df.eq(0).all()]
Out[71]:
   b
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

If we want to check those that do NOT sum up to `0`:

```
In [78]: df.loc[:, df.sum().astype(bool)]
Out[78]:
   b
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

Comment: Hey, my second solution is similar to yours... want me to remove it?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, everything is fine :)