# Best way to remove all columns and rows with zero sum from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I delete rows and columns in a Pandas dataframe that contain all the zeros. For example, I have a df:

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1
```

I want to delete 2nd and 6th row (line) and also the 4th column. The output should look like:

```
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
```

Comment: thanks @quang for editing

Comment: Are all entries non-negative? If not, you ask two different questions in the title and the body of the post.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. As an aside, are you using 0/1 instead of actual boolean values?

Comment: @AMC valid point. I will try to share what i tried and didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here we go:

```
ad = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(ad)

df.drop(df.loc[df.sum(axis=1)==0].index, inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.sum()==0], inplace=True)
```

The code above will drop the row/column, when the sum of the row/column is `zero`. This is achived by calucating the sum along the axis `1` for rows and `0` for columns and then dropting the row/column with a sum of `0` (`df.drop(...)`)

Comment: Why not just `df.loc[df.sum(axis=1) != 0]`?

Comment: I thought, he wants to delete it from the same dateframe. Your sugestion works too.

Comment: yes this works for rows but not for columns. we still have 4th column with all zeros (or sum of zero)

Comment: I edited the original comment with a row for the columns

Answer (score 0):

found similar question already answered

[Pandas DataFrame, How do I remove all columns and rows that sum to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573052/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-remove-all-columns-and-rows-that-sum-to-0)

df.loc[(df!=0).any(1), (df!=0).any(0)]

But this does not work inplace. How can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.loc[(df!=0).any(1), (df!=0).any(0)]
```

In addition to the question when someone wants to drop a column/row, where every value is 0, the solution above will do this. First you getting a table with False/True's for the dataframe for the condition `df != 0` and with (`df != 0).any()`) you will get whether any element is True, potentially over an axis ([from the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)).