# Deleting columns with sum of zero (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing multiple excel files into a single df and want to delete all columns in the final df which have a sum of zero. I've tried the below, but no columns are deleted. I definitely have many columns which have a sum of zero.

```
for i in df_Final_hours.columns:
            if df_Final_hours[i].sum() == 0:
                df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.drop(i,axis=1)
```

Comment: [```df_Final_hours.loc[:, (df_Final_hours.sum(axis=0) != 0)]```](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573052/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-remove-all-columns-and-rows-that-sum-to-0)

Answer (score 0):

Another option apart from the one raised by the user **'sophocles'** in his comment which is:

`df_Final_hours.loc[:, (df_Final_hours.sum(axis=0) != 0)]`

You can also use:

```
lista = [] 
headers = list(df_Final_hours.columns.values)
for i in headers:
    if df_Final_hours[i].sum() != 0:
        lista.append(i)
    else: pass
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours[lista]
```