# Drop row in pandas dataframe if any value in the row equals zero

Tags: python, pandas

How do I drop a row if any of the values in the row equal zero?

I would normally use df.dropna() for NaN values but not sure how to do it with "0" values.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

i think the easiest way is looking at rows where all values are not equal to 0:

```
df[(df != 0).all(1)]
```

Comment: I chose this answer because it is the most efficient in terms of coding but both answers appear to be accurate.

Answer (score 25):

You could make a boolean frame and then use `any`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,2],[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[4,5,6]])
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  0  2
1  1  2  3
2  0  1  2
3  4  5  6
>>> df == 0
       0      1      2
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
>>> df = df[~(df == 0).any(axis=1)]
>>> df
   0  1  2
1  1  2  3
3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 24):

Although it is late, someone else might find it helpful.
I had similar issue. But the following worked best for me.

```
df =pd.read_csv(r'your file')
df =df[df['your column name'] !=0]
```

reference:
[Drop rows with all zeros in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame)
see @ikbel benabdessamad

Comment: Think this is the most legible if we just want to focus on one (or a group) of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Assume a simple DataFrame as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,0,3,4,0,9])
```

Pick non-zero values which turns all zero values into nan and remove nan-values

```
df=df[df!=0].dropna()

df
```

Output:

```
    0
0   1.0
1   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
6   9.0
```