# How to delete the entire row if any of its value is 0 in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In the below example I only want to retain the row 1 and 2 
I want to delete all the rows which has 0 anywhere across the column:

```
kt  b   tt  mky depth
1   1   1   1   1   4
2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   0   3   3
4   0   4   0   0   0
5   5   5   5   5   0
```

[image]

the output should read like below:

```
kt  b   tt  mky depth
1   1   1   1   1   4
2   2   2   2   2   2
```

[image]

I have tried:

```
df.loc[(df!=0).any(axis=1)]
```

But it deletes the row only if all of its corresponding columns are 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop row in pandas dataframe if any value in the row equals zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020312/drop-row-in-pandas-dataframe-if-any-value-in-the-row-equals-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close, need [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per row:

```
df = df.loc[(df!=0).all(axis=1)] 
print (df)
   kt  b  tt  mky  depth
1   1  1   1    1      4
2   2  2   2    2      2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df!=0)
      kt     b     tt    mky  depth
1   True  True   True   True   True
2   True  True   True   True   True
3   True  True  False   True   True
4  False  True  False  False  False
5   True  True   True   True  False

print ((df!=0).all(axis=1))
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Alternative solution with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` for row with changed mask `df == 0` and inversing by `~`:

```
df = df.loc[~(df==0).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Again its @jezrael the savior :) Thank you