# My Pandas dataframe shows the number 0 as not null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to delete every row that contains 0 in order to have cleaner data. However as you can see on the image it shows that 0 is not a null value. Can you guys help me on this?
Thank you.

[image: output of my data framework]

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html?highlight=notnull#pandas.DataFrame.notnull) the method `DataFrame.notnull()` check if the value are NA, and not for the values equal to zero or in your case a string because you replaced it with 'NA'.

Now to do what you want you can do:

```
df[(df != 0).all(1)]
```

As describe in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020312/drop-row-in-pandas-dataframe-if-any-value-in-the-row-equals-zero/27020741)

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you are trying `df.replace(0,'NA')` you are subbing in the `string` value of `NA` which is **not** `NULL`.

You can just use `np.nan` there like : `df.replace(0,np.nan)` [with `import numpy as np`]

Answer (score 0):

By using a replace, you might want to use the following:

```py
df.replace(0, np.nan).dropna()
```

It basically replaces zeroes by np.nan wich can be eliminated by pandas' `.dropna()`