# How to drop rows in a data frame having any entry with the value zero ? ('collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'dropna')

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to drop all rows from dataframe where any entry in any column of the row has the value zero.
I am placing a Minimal Working Example below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('trial.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
df
```

I am getting the dataframe as follows

```
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',   type  query  answers
          0  abc    100       90
          1  def      0        0
          2  ghi      0        0
          3  jkl      5        1
          4  mno      1        1)])
```

I am trying to remove the rows using the dropna() using the following code.

```
df = df.dropna()
df
```

i am getting an error saying 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'dropna''. I tried going through the various answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020312/drop-row-in-pandas-dataframe-if-any-value-in-the-row-equals-zero), but the error remains.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block or include synthetic data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: `import numpy as np`, `df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)`, and then `df.dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you for replying @Trenton McKinney. I have edited my question. But even when i use df.head(10), i am getting the same type of error - 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: An `OrderedDict` isn't a dataframe. If you do `df = pd.read_excel('trial.xlsx',sheet_name=None)`, then do `df.head()` what happens?

Comment: Unfortunately your variable ```df``` is not referring to a dataframe. You can check what datatype your variable is by passing the object to the ```type``` function like so ```type(df)```. You can create a dataframe from your OrderedDict like this ```df = pandas.DataFrame(my_ordered_dict)```

Comment: Thank you @ Trenton McKinney. I get the same error as earlier like _collections.OrderedDict object has no attribute 'head'_, upon running `df.head()`. You are right, `df` is a OrderedDict and not a DataFrame

Comment: Thank you @el_oso. I tried out `df = pandas.DataFrame(my_ordered_dict)`, but giot the following error _ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index_

Comment: I got around to getting a dataframe by saving my file as a .csv instead of .xlsx. However `df1` in the code given below also has rows with zero in them, `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('trial.csv')
print(df)
df1 = df.loc[(df!=0).any(1)]
print(df1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting an OrderedDict object is because you are feeding `sheet_name=None` parameter to the `read_excel` method of the library. This will load all the sheets into a dictionary of DataFrames.

If you only need the one sheet, specify it in the `sheet_name` parameter, otherwise remove it to read the first sheet.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('trial.xlsx') #without sheet_name will read first sheet

print(type(df))
df = df.dropna()
```

or

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('trial.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') #reads specific sheet

print(type(df))
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: Wow!! Yes it worked. Now i am able to get the DataFrame from .xlsx also. I tried `df = df.replace(0, np.nan)`
`df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)` `df1=df.dropna()` and got the rows with zeroes removed!! Thank you!!