# How to count number of rows per day in a MultiIndex'ed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with a two-level MultiIndex. The first level `date` is a DatetimeIndex and the second level `name` is just some strings. The data has 10-minute intervals.

**How can I group by date on the first level of this MultiIndex and count the number of rows I have per day?**

I suspect that the DatetimeIndex coupled into a MultiIndex is giving me problems, since doing

```
data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).count()
```

gives me

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

I've also tried writing

```
data.groupby(data.index.levels[0].date).count()
```

which leads to

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

How could I, for example, make the grouper longer (i.e., include duplicate index values, omitting of which now make it shorter than the axis)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataframe in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `level` keyword in `Grouper`.  (Also note that `TimeGrouper` is deprecated).  This param is

> the level for the target index.

Example DataFrame:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01', freq='10MIN', periods=1000)
strs = ['aa'] * 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,2), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((dates, strs)))
```

Solution:

```
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=0)).count())
              0    1
2017-01-01  144  144
2017-01-02  144  144
2017-01-03  144  144
2017-01-04  144  144
2017-01-05  144  144
2017-01-06  144  144
2017-01-07  136  136
```

Update: you noted in your comments that your resulting counts have zeros you'd like to drop.  For instance, say your DataFrame is actually missing some days:

```
df = df.drop(df.index[140:400])
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=0)).count())
              0    1
2017-01-01  140  140
2017-01-02    0    0
2017-01-03   32   32
2017-01-04  144  144
2017-01-05  144  144
2017-01-06  144  144
2017-01-07  136  136
```

To my knowledge there's no way to exclude zero counts within `.count`.  Instead, you could use your result from above to drop zeros.

First solution (may be less preferable, because it converts and `int` result to `float` when `np.nan` is introduced, would be

```
res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=0)).count()
res = res.replace(0, np.nan).dropna()
```

Second and better solution, in my opinion, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame):

```
res = res[(res.T != 0).any()]
print(res) # notice - excludes 2017-01-02
              0    1
2017-01-01  140  140
2017-01-03   32   32
2017-01-04  144  144
2017-01-05  144  144
2017-01-06  144  144
2017-01-07  136  136
```

`.any` is from NumPy, ported over to pandas, and returns True when any element is True over requested axis.

Comment: Thanks, Brad, you answered my question perfectly. As a learning opportunity, I noticed that I get rows of zero counts and appending `.dropna()` to the `.groupby().count()` statement doesn't drop those. Any way to make the `Grouper` drop zero counts straight away in the same line?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Dataframe looks like this

```
d=pd.DataFrame([['Mon','foo',3],['Tue','bar',6],['Wed','qux',9]],
               columns=['date','name','amount'])\
              .set_index(['date','name'])
```

you can remove the name from the index only for this grouping operation

```
d.reset_index('name', drop=True)\
 .groupby('date')\
 ['amount'].count()
```