# Delete rows with all the zeros elements in all columns exceptionally leaving a single non zero column in pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Df with 2 million rows *10 columns.
I want to delete all the zero elements in a row for all columns except single column with non zero elements.

**Ex. My Df like:**

```
Índex   Time    a   b   c   d   e
0       1       0   0   0   0   0
1       2       1   2   0   0   0 
2       3       0   0   0   0   0
3       4       5   0   0   0   0  
4       5       0   0   0   0   0   
5       6       7   0   0   0   0
```

**What I needed:**

```
Índex   Time        a   b   c   d   e
    0       2       1   2   0   0   0 
    1       4       5   0   0   0   0  
    2       6       7   0   0   0   0
```

**My Requirement:**
Requirement 1:
Leaving the 1st column (Time) it should check for zero elements in every rows. If all column values are zero delete that particular row.
Requirement 2:
Finally I want my Index to be updated properly

**What I tried:**
I have been looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame).
I understood the logic used but I wasn't able to reproduce the result for my requirement.

I hope there will be a simple method to do the operation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select all columns without first, comapre for not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and test at least one `True` per rows by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternative with remove column `Time`:

```
df = df[df.drop('Time', axis=1).ne(0).any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
   Time  a  b  c  d  e
0     2  1  2  0  0  0
1     4  5  0  0  0  0
2     6  7  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: @esakkiponraj.e - how working `df[df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).any(axis=1).values].reset_index(drop=True)` ?