# Deleting rows with conditionals in python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, delete-row

I have a multilabel classification problem.

I would like to delete rows thave **a value (0) in all** of the 35 columns of the dataframe, **except** ['Doc'] column.

Example of dataframe

```
Doc   Big    Small    Int    Bor   Drama
j2     0       0        0      0     0
i9     1       0        1      1     0
ui8    0       0        0      1     0
po4    0       1        0      0     0
po9    0       0        0      0     0
```

Here's the expected outcome

```
Doc   Big    Small    Int    Bor   Drama
i9     1       0        1      1     0
ui8    0       0        0      1     0
po4    0       1        0      0     0
```

These are the rows I would like to delete:

```
 j2     0       0        0      0     0
 po9    0       0        0      0     0
```

Here's how I count them:

```
rowSums = df.iloc[:,2:].sum(axis=1)
no_labelled = (rowSums==0).sum(axis=0)
print("no.docs with no label =", no_labelled)
```

no.docs with no label = 60

How can I delete these 60 rows from the dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Please read the guidelines, its easier for us to answer if you provide example data and example expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop rows with all zeros in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

You can just extract the required dataframe and assign it to the old variable, rather than explicitly calling `del`:

```
df =  df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1) > 0, :]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the rows if column sum (other than first) is 0. You can try this

```
df2.drop(df2[df2.loc[:,1:].sum(axis=1) == 0].index)
```

Comment: Please provide additional information as to what this answer is doing.  Code only answers are flagged as low-quality by Stack Overflow.