# Drop all rows in pandas dataframe that are all only 0 or NA

Tags: python, pandas, na

expanding on [Drop rows with all zeros in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22649693/6819862), how would I edit that solution to remove all rows from a data frame that contain only 0 and NAs.

I tried:

```
df.loc[~(df == 0 | df.isnan()).all(axis=1))]
```

but got `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

**EDIT**

`df[(~(df == 0 | df.isna())).all(axis=1)]` works for one of my dataframes but not the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': {'Total': -3.637978807091713e-09}, 'y': {'Total': -3.637978807091713e-09}, 'z': {'Total': -3.637978807091713e-09}, 'a': {'Total': 0.0}, 'b': {'Total': 1387241.5974624965}, 'c': {'Total': 1387241.5974624965}})
```

When I run `df[(~(df == 0 | df.isna())).all(axis=1)]`, I get an empty dataframe when the row should not be dropped because there exists a value that is not equal to either 0 or `NA`.

Comment: Use `df.eq(0)` or do `(df == 0) | ...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you need to wrap the invert under parenthesis :

```
df[~((df==0)|(df.isna())).all(1)]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `df = pd.DataFrame({'x': {'Total': -3.637978807091713e-09},
 'y': {'Total': -3.637978807091713e-09},
 'z': {'Total': -3.637978807091713e-09},
 'a': {'Total': 0.0},
 'b': {'Total': 1387241.5974624965},
 'c': {'Total': 1387241.5974624965}})`

Comment: @cpage i didnt get your point, if you are looking to drop rows which has 0 or `NaN` in any columns and not all columns, replace `all(1)` with `any(1)`

Comment: `df[(~(df == 0 | df.isna())).all(axis=1)]` drops the one row of this case when it should not be dropped because there is a col that is not either 0 or `NaN`.

Comment: @cpage probably better if you can edit your question to show why this doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

We can use the inverse logic of Morgan Laws to get rid of the operator `~`.
Sometimes it is good to use `.mul` instead of `&` to avoid the use of parentheses.

```
df[df.notna().mul(df.ne(0)).all(axis = 1)]
#df[(df.notna() & df.ne(0)).all(axis = 1)]
```